# Definite integral substitution problem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution

I had to solve the following definite integral, i solved it by substitution but I checked many times and I can't find out why the result I get is wrong. I know it can be solved by parts, but I want to understand what is wrong with my reasoning specifically.
The integral is the following:
\[
I = \int_2^4 \frac{\arctan \frac{2}{x}}{x^3} dx
\]
I thought about substituting
\[
t = \frac{2}{x} \qquad \implies \qquad dt = -\frac{2}{x^2} dx
\]
Then I rewrote the integral as follows
\[
I = -\frac{1}{2} \int_2^4 \frac{\arctan \frac2x}{x} \cdot \left(-\frac{2}{x^2}\right) dx
\]
If $x=2$ then $t=\frac{2}{2}=1$, Whilst if $x=4$ then $t=\frac{2}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$; also by the definition of $t$ I get that $x=\frac{2}{t}$ so by making the substitution I get
\[
I =-\frac{1}{2} \int_{1}^{\frac 12} \frac{\arctan t}{\frac{2}{t}} dt = \frac{1}{4} \int_{\frac12}^{1} t \arctan t \; dt
\]
But at this point by checking the integral with wolfram alpha the result is already different from the one I get using the original integral for some reason, why is that?

Comment: Everything seems correct to me. I tried also to compute the two definite integrals with wolfram alpha and the results agree. Are you sure you haven't made any mistakes checking the integrals with wolfram alpha?

Answer (score 0):

Both integrals are the same, and the value is
$$
\int t\arctan t dt = \frac{1}{2}t^2\arctan t-\frac{t}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\arctan t
$$
and
$$
\frac14 \int_{1/2}^1 t\arctan t dt = \frac{1}{4}(\arctan 1 -\frac14 -\frac{5}{8}\arctan\frac12)\approx 0.061404602
$$